# Why my GPS not showing exact location address?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, gps

I'm new to android coding. My Gps connecting not showing the exact location address. Its just showing my town name n county name. How to make it to get specific address, like house number, street, city, etc.

This is my current output. = Your Location is Kajang 43009 Malaysia MY

This is location.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper" >
    
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textlocation"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Location"
        android:textSize="35dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is GPStracker.java

```js
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

 private final Context mContext;

 // flag for GPS status
 boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

 // flag for network status
 boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

 // flag for GPS status
 boolean canGetLocation = false;

 Location location; // location
 double latitude; // latitude
 double longitude; // longitude

 // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
 private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

 // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
 private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

 // Declaring a Location Manager
 protected LocationManager locationManager;

 public GPSTracker(Context context) {
  this.mContext = context;
  getLocation();
 }

 public Location getLocation() {
  try {
   locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
     .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

   // getting GPS status
   isGPSEnabled = locationManager
     .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

   // getting network status
   isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
     .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

   if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
    // no network provider is enabled
   } else {
    this.canGetLocation = true;
    if (isNetworkEnabled) {
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
       LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
       MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
       MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
     Log.d("Network", "Network");
     if (locationManager != null) {
      location = locationManager
        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
      if (location != null) {
       latitude = location.getLatitude();
       longitude = location.getLongitude();
      }
     }
    }
    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
    if (isGPSEnabled) {
     if (location == null) {
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
      Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
      if (locationManager != null) {
       location = locationManager
         .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
       if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return location;
 }
 
 /**
  * Stop using GPS listener
  * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
  * */
 public void stopUsingGPS(){
  if(locationManager != null){
   locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
  }  
 }
 
 /**
  * Function to get latitude
  * */
 public double getLatitude(){
  if(location != null){
   latitude = location.getLatitude();
  }
  
  // return latitude
  return latitude;
 }
 
 /**
  * Function to get longitude
  * */
 public double getLongitude(){
  if(location != null){
   longitude = location.getLongitude();
  }
  
  // return longitude
  return longitude;
 }
 
 /**
  * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
  * @return boolean
  * */
 public boolean canGetLocation() {
  return this.canGetLocation;
 }
 
 /**
  * Function to show settings alert dialog
  * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
  * */
 public void showSettingsAlert(){
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
     
        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
 
        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
 
        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
             mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
 
        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
 
        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
 }

 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
 }

 @Override
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
 }

 @Override
 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
 }

 @Override
 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
 }

 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
  return null;
 }

}
```

This is LocationActivity.java

```js
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LocationActivity extends Activity {
 
 Geocoder geocoder;
 List<Address> addresses;
 Location loc;
 
 // GPS Location
 GPSTracker gps;

 
 // Getting intent data
 Intent i = getIntent();
 
 TextView detailsx;
  
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.location);
  
  
  detailsx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textlocation);
  
  // creating GPS Class object
  gps = new GPSTracker(this);
  
  Double latx = gps.getLatitude();
  Double longx= gps.getLongitude();
 
 try {
  geocoder = new Geocoder(LocationActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
  addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latx, longx, 1);
  StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
  
  if (geocoder.isPresent()) {
   Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);
    
   String localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
   String city = returnAddress.getCountryName();
   String region_code = returnAddress.getCountryCode();
   String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();
   
   String xx = localityString +" "+zipcode + " "+ city + " " + region_code ;
   
   String messagex= "Your Location is:" + " "+ xx  ;
            detailsx.setText(messagex);
   
  } }catch(Exception e){
   
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look I see that you are not using the onLocationChanged method that the locationlistener interface requires to provide the location object that you would get longitude and latitude from.

As for getting an actual street address if that's what you want, easiest way would be to use an API that can provide the approximate street address based on the longitude and latitude etc (one of the Google APIs provides this service)

Also, if you are using an emulator to test this (e.g. genymotion) then it will only provide the specific static location you specify in the emulator